# Unit testing of code ported from a CRC32 implementation originally in C?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

This is a port of a C implementation written by Craig Bruce that had been made available in the public domain, which in turn had been based on the byte-oriented implementation:

> "File Verification Using CRC" by Mark R. Nelson in Dr. Dobb's Journal, May 1992, pp. 64-67.

The original C implementation can be [found here](http://www.csbruce.com/software/crc32.c)

I am trying to write a `NUnit` test for it and need some help to figure out where to start, what conditions to state. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MCC.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Calculates CRC32 Values
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     This is a port of a C implementaion written by Craig Bruce that had
    ///     been made available in the public domain, which in turn had been based on the byte-oriented implementation "File
    ///     Verification Using CRC" by Mark R. Nelson in Dr. Dobb's Journal, May 1992, pp. 64-67.
    ///     The original C implementation can be found here:
    ///     http://www.csbruce.com/software/crc32.c
    /// </remarks>
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1704:IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", MessageId = "Crc")]
    public static class Crc32
    {
        private static readonly uint[] CrcTable =
        {
            0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA, 0x076DC419, 0x706AF48F, 0xE963A535,
            0x9E6495A3, 0x0EDB8832, 0x79DCB8A4, 0xE0D5E91E, 0x97D2D988, 0x09B64C2B, 0x7EB17CBD,
            0xE7B82D07, 0x90BF1D91, 0x1DB71064, 0x6AB020F2, 0xF3B97148, 0x84BE41DE, 0x1ADAD47D,
            0x6DDDE4EB, 0xF4D4B551, 0x83D385C7, 0x136C9856, 0x646BA8C0, 0xFD62F97A, 0x8A65C9EC,
            0x14015C4F, 0x63066CD9, 0xFA0F3D63, 0x8D080DF5, 0x3B6E20C8, 0x4C69105E, 0xD56041E4,
            0xA2677172, 0x3C03E4D1, 0x4B04D447, 0xD20D85FD, 0xA50AB56B, 0x35B5A8FA, 0x42B2986C,
            0xDBBBC9D6, 0xACBCF940, 0x32D86CE3, 0x45DF5C75, 0xDCD60DCF, 0xABD13D59, 0x26D930AC,
            0x51DE003A, 0xC8D75180, 0xBFD06116, 0x21B4F4B5, 0x56B3C423, 0xCFBA9599, 0xB8BDA50F,
            0x2802B89E, 0x5F058808, 0xC60CD9B2, 0xB10BE924, 0x2F6F7C87, 0x58684C11, 0xC1611DAB,
            0xB6662D3D, 0x76DC4190, 0x01DB7106, 0x98D220BC, 0xEFD5102A, 0x71B18589, 0x06B6B51F,
            0x9FBFE4A5, 0xE8B8D433, 0x7807C9A2, 0x0F00F934, 0x9609A88E, 0xE10E9818, 0x7F6A0DBB,
            0x086D3D2D, 0x91646C97, 0xE6635C01, 0x6B6B51F4, 0x1C6C6162, 0x856530D8, 0xF262004E,
            0x6C0695ED, 0x1B01A57B, 0x8208F4C1, 0xF50FC457, 0x65B0D9C6, 0x12B7E950, 0x8BBEB8EA,
            0xFCB9887C, 0x62DD1DDF, 0x15DA2D49, 0x8CD37CF3, 0xFBD44C65, 0x4DB26158, 0x3AB551CE,
            0xA3BC0074, 0xD4BB30E2, 0x4ADFA541, 0x3DD895D7, 0xA4D1C46D, 0xD3D6F4FB, 0x4369E96A,
            0x346ED9FC, 0xAD678846, 0xDA60B8D0, 0x44042D73, 0x33031DE5, 0xAA0A4C5F, 0xDD0D7CC9,
            0x5005713C, 0x270241AA, 0xBE0B1010, 0xC90C2086, 0x5768B525, 0x206F85B3, 0xB966D409,
            0xCE61E49F, 0x5EDEF90E, 0x29D9C998, 0xB0D09822, 0xC7D7A8B4, 0x59B33D17, 0x2EB40D81,
            0xB7BD5C3B, 0xC0BA6CAD, 0xEDB88320, 0x9ABFB3B6, 0x03B6E20C, 0x74B1D29A, 0xEAD54739,
            0x9DD277AF, 0x04DB2615, 0x73DC1683, 0xE3630B12, 0x94643B84, 0x0D6D6A3E, 0x7A6A5AA8,
            0xE40ECF0B, 0x9309FF9D, 0x0A00AE27, 0x7D079EB1, 0xF00F9344, 0x8708A3D2, 0x1E01F268,
            0x6906C2FE, 0xF762575D, 0x806567CB, 0x196C3671, 0x6E6B06E7, 0xFED41B76, 0x89D32BE0,
            0x10DA7A5A, 0x67DD4ACC, 0xF9B9DF6F, 0x8EBEEFF9, 0x17B7BE43, 0x60B08ED5, 0xD6D6A3E8,
            0xA1D1937E, 0x38D8C2C4, 0x4FDFF252, 0xD1BB67F1, 0xA6BC5767, 0x3FB506DD, 0x48B2364B,
            0xD80D2BDA, 0xAF0A1B4C, 0x36034AF6, 0x41047A60, 0xDF60EFC3, 0xA867DF55, 0x316E8EEF,
            0x4669BE79, 0xCB61B38C, 0xBC66831A, 0x256FD2A0, 0x5268E236, 0xCC0C7795, 0xBB0B4703,
            0x220216B9, 0x5505262F, 0xC5BA3BBE, 0xB2BD0B28, 0x2BB45A92, 0x5CB36A04, 0xC2D7FFA7,
            0xB5D0CF31, 0x2CD99E8B, 0x5BDEAE1D, 0x9B64C2B0, 0xEC63F226, 0x756AA39C, 0x026D930A,
            0x9C0906A9, 0xEB0E363F, 0x72076785, 0x05005713, 0x95BF4A82, 0xE2B87A14, 0x7BB12BAE,
            0x0CB61B38, 0x92D28E9B, 0xE5D5BE0D, 0x7CDCEFB7, 0x0BDBDF21, 0x86D3D2D4, 0xF1D4E242,
            0x68DDB3F8, 0x1FDA836E, 0x81BE16CD, 0xF6B9265B, 0x6FB077E1, 0x18B74777, 0x88085AE6,
            0xFF0F6A70, 0x66063BCA, 0x11010B5C, 0x8F659EFF, 0xF862AE69, 0x616BFFD3, 0x166CCF45,
            0xA00AE278, 0xD70DD2EE, 0x4E048354, 0x3903B3C2, 0xA7672661, 0xD06016F7, 0x4969474D,
            0x3E6E77DB, 0xAED16A4A, 0xD9D65ADC, 0x40DF0B66, 0x37D83BF0, 0xA9BCAE53, 0xDEBB9EC5,
            0x47B2CF7F, 0x30B5FFE9, 0xBDBDF21C, 0xCABAC28A, 0x53B39330, 0x24B4A3A6, 0xBAD03605,
            0xCDD70693, 0x54DE5729, 0x23D967BF, 0xB3667A2E, 0xC4614AB8, 0x5D681B02, 0x2A6F2B94,
            0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D
        };

        /// <summary>
        ///     Computes the CRC-32 hash of the specified bytes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="byteBuffer">The bytes to compute the hash for</param>
        /// <returns>The CRC-32 hash of the specified bytes</returns>
        public static uint ComputeHash(byte[] byteBuffer)
        {
            if (byteBuffer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("byteBuffer");
            }
            long len = byteBuffer.LongLength;

            uint crc32 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                crc32 = (crc32 >> 8) ^ CrcTable[(crc32 ^ byteBuffer[i]) & 0xFF];
            }
            return (crc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a set of known input and check the output - generate these from a known-good implementation. You'll also want to check the edge-case and contract assertions.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

Since it is static with no dependencies, unit testing is as simple as calling the method with known inputs and expected results:

```
[Test]
public void TestThatHashOfHelloWorldIs98766()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(98766, 
        Crc32.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Hello World")));
}
```

You'll probably want to do a bunch of cases, so look at using parameterized tests or [`[Theory]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5.1) to DRY up your test code.

One requirement is that you will need another, trusted CRC library to determine the test cases, of course.

You'll also want to test the edge cases, like:

```
[Test]
public void TestNullThrows()
{
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => Crc32.ComputeHash(null));
}
```

And if you suspect performance will be an issue on large computations, set a [MaxTime](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=maxtime&r=2.5.1):

```
[Test, Maxtime(50)]
public void TimedTest()
{
    Crc32.ComputeHash(someVeryLongByteArrayHere);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, you helped me a lot!